# Choosing the Better Approach for Studying Algebraic Topology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, soft-question, book-recommendation

I'm a third year undergraduate student and I had a basic course on Algebraic Topology which covered chapters 1-6 of *Armstrong's Basic Topology*, which consists of Homotopy, Fundamental Group, Simplicial Complexes and van Kampen theorem. I'm going to do a project on Teichmüller Theory and I need to learn some Homology and Cohomology. Also I want to gain a deeper understanding of Algebraic Topology in general.

In my way to find a good book to study Algebraic Topology, I didn't find *Hatcher's* book interesting because of its style of exposition but since I've had graduate courses in Complex Analysis and Smooth Manifolds, *Fulton's Algebraic Topology* seemed really interesting to me because of its approach which uses Analysis and Geometry as motivation for developing Algebraic Topology. But on the other hand, I've heard that Fulton's approach is a bit old and some other books such as *Rotman's An Introduction to Algebraic Topology* pursue a more modern and categorical viewpoint (Btw Rotman's book seemed good to me).

Now, I'm a bit stuck between Fulton's book and Rotman's book. Is there any significant difference between these books' approaches? Should I study Rotman's or Fulton's? Is there any better book than these two?

Comment: [Here is the textbook of my first course in algebraic topology](https://www.amazon.com/Algebraic-Topology-Course-Mathematics-Lecture/dp/0805335579) Also, each book of Rotman is excellent. [Another nice book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387979267)

Comment: For Teichmuller Theory (or anything to do with the plane) Cech cohomology is very, very powerful.  Munkres' algebraic topology book probably goes the deepest on Cech stuff - though it is VERY much the flavor of a "topologist's topology book" compared to the others you mentioned.